# Jetty deploys WAR file in incorrect path

Tags: jetty-9

I'm using jetty (not embedded) with a single WAR file inside docker container.
When i start the jetty using `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar "$JETTY_HOME/start.jar"`
the jetty is deploying the WAR file located in `$JETTY_HOME/webapps` into `/tmp/jetty-RandomNumber-WAR_FILE_NAME-any-number.dir`
this isn't good because i want the extracted WAR to always be in the same folder and not to create a different folder everytime i restart jetty.
also i want to deploy the WAR file into `$JETTY_HOME/webapps/WAR_FILE_NAME` folder.
How can i configure that via jetty XML files or by using a parameter that i can send to jetty when running it?